# Why are the field types different and the clickhouse query results are different

Tags: clickhouse

I have two sql statements.

```
    SELECT
    sku_id,
    inventory_state,
    count() AS sumNum,
    sum(in_price) AS sumInPrice,
    sum(out_price) AS sumOutPrice
FROM
    imspc_inventory_lifecycle_bills_2021
WHERE
    sku_id IN (1422796349332701186, 1415500436516028417)
    AND inventory_state IN ('1', '5', '6')
    AND purchase_depart_id = 8
GROUP BY
    sku_id,
    inventory_state
```

and

```
    SELECT
    sku_id,
    inventory_state,
    count() AS sumNum,
    sum(in_price) AS sumInPrice,
    sum(out_price) AS sumOutPrice
FROM
    imspc_inventory_lifecycle_bills_2021
WHERE
    sku_id IN (1422796349332701186, 1415500436516028417)
    AND inventory_state IN ('1', '5', '6')
    AND purchase_depart_id = '8'
GROUP BY
    sku_id,
    inventory_state
```

purchase_depart_id field Type is int64.
first SQL result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STewN.png)

second SQL result is right.
What causes this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaterializeMySQL ? It's a bug. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/25794